# How to display Javascript filter results with a minumum of 2 characters entered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, filter

I'm using a filter search box but I want it to only start displaying results when a minimum of two letters are inputted as I have a lot that needs filtered through and the list is massive when you start to search due to it only requiring one letter.

I've tried searching for a way around this but have had no luck, my javascript knowledge is really not up to scratch so apologies if this is a simple fix.

My code is:

```js
document.querySelector('#searchInput').addEventListener('input', () => {
  let filter = document.querySelector('#searchInput').value.toUpperCase();
  document.querySelectorAll('#productli li').forEach(el => {
    let a = el.querySelector('a'); // gets the first only
    el.style.display = filter && (a.textContent || a.innerText).toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1 ? 'list-item' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
#productli li {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Enter your search term here">
<ul id="productli">
  <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Search for debounce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest is an if, testing the length and return

I also suggest you cache the list

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('#productli li');
document.getElementById('searchInput').addEventListener('input', function() { // now you can use "this"
  let filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
  if (filter && filter.length<3) return
  list.forEach(el => {
    let a = el.querySelector('a'); // gets the first only
    el.style.display = filter && (a.textContent || a.innerText).toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1 ? 'list-item' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
#productli li {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Enter your search term here">
<ul id="productli">
  <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great and has solved the character issue, however, with this when I clear the search box the results now still display.

Comment: You can also toggle the display of productli when the filter is empty

Comment: You, Sir, are amazing. Thanks so much! You have saved me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy and straightforward way to achieve this would be to simply add an `if` and check whether or not `filter.length >= 2`

Plus, if you want to "de-filter" and stop showing the results, you can add an `else` where you set `el.style.display = none`

This can be optimized, but always remember to [keep it simple, stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)